# How can I re-run my JUnit tests with different JVM args?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, junit

In essence, I have a few configuration properties that are usually set through JVM args at runtime.

```
final props = [
    "-Dproject.debug=true",
    "-Dproject.legacy.function=true",
    "-Dproject.secure.impl=true"
]
```

Above are some examples. Depending on the property, some classes that I am testing will operate differently, if `project.legacy.function` is enabled it will fallback to a legacy implementation rather than using the modern one.

```
test {
    final props = [
        "-Dproject.debug=true",
        "-Dproject.legacy.function=true",
        "-Dproject.secure.impl=true"
    ]

    jvmArgs props
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

This is my test task in gradle. I want to somehow be able to re-run it, with a different set of jvmArgs, for example, having the above functions set to false instead. I can't find a way to do this from within my task. The only things I've found on StackOverflow and elsewhere demonstrate how to re-run JUnit tests through `@Repeat` or from within the Test classes themselves, but that won't work for me since my properties are defined through a finalized class, and internally used.

```java
class Properties {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = get("project.debug");
    public static final boolean LEGACY_FUNCTION = get("project.legacy.function");
}
```

Elsewhere..

```java
class SomeClass {
    SomeType someMethod(SomeOtherType var1) {
        if (Properties.LEGACY_FUNCTION) {
            // do one thing
        }
        else {
            // do other thing
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to re-run the JUnit task and have different properties?

EDIT:

I'm going to try and use pseudo-code to demonstrate what I mean, for clarity sake.

```
test {
    final props = [
        "-Dproject.debug=true",
        "-Dproject.legacy.function=true",
        "-Dproject.secure.impl=true"
    ]

    jvmArgs props
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    repeat {
        final props2 = [
            "-Dproject.debug=true",
            "-Dproject.legacy.function=false",
            "-Dproject.secure.impl=true"
        ]

        jvmArgs props2
        useJUnitPlatform()
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

I don't mind having to manually write out the `true/false` (I could perhaps use an iterative randomizer anyways), all I really need is to know if I can re-run a test task in some form through the gradle script, so that I only have to do `./gradlew test` and have it run through all my iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a Gradle property that can be used as a switch to determine whether or not `project.legacy.function` should be `true` or `false`. For example:

```
tasks.named("test", Test::class) {
    val legacyFunction = project.hasProperty("legacyFunction")
    val args = listOf(
        "-Dproject.debug=true",
        "-Dproject.legacy.function=$legacyFunction",
        "-Dproject.secure.impl=true"
    )
    jvmArgs(args)
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

And executing as `./gradlew -PlegacyFunction` will result in `project.legacy.function` being `true`. Omitting the property will make it false.

Comment: I’ll be honest, thats not really much different from how I have it now. I could also easily just change my prop to true or false manually, but i’d prefer a more robust and automatic way, where I can simply re-run the task on its own with the different properties

Comment: _Something_ has to be set somewhere to control `true`/`false`. So I'm not sure how you're really going to automatically achieve that or what you're looking for.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit, maybe that will make it more clear.

Comment: That to me is something that JUnit Jupiter can accomplish using extensions. Specifically the [system properties](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/system-properties/) extension from Pioneer along with `@ValueSource` and `@ParameterizedTest`

Comment: Are you sure that would work for where a property is saved into a `public static final` variable? I imagine the value would be constant at that stage and no longer update, regardless of what I change my system property to.